# How to attach a locally imported thumbnail and a locally imported image to an embed on discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am new to python and I am learning by making bots for discord. I am making a memory jar bot and I am using embeds when memories are retrieved. Along the message as well as any images associated with the message attached to the embed, it also picks a random photo in a collection for the thumbnail of the embed. However, both the images associated with the message and the image for the thumbnail are imported locally. Is there a way to attach both these images to the same embed?

```
memory,date,file_name = memory 
mem_file_info = File("C:\\*\\Desktop\\Discord Bots\\Memory Jar Bot\\" + file_name,filename = file_name)
embed = Embed (title = '\u2619' + date, description = '\U0001F495' + memory + '\U0001F495', colour = Colour.red()) 
embed.set_image(url="attachment://" + file_name)
embed.set_author (name = author_name, icon_url = author_profil_pic_url)  
embed.set_footer(text = f'''Memory pulled by {context.message.author}''') 
thumbnail_file = File("C:\\*\\Discord Bots\\Memory Jar Bot\\" + rand_thumbnail_pic,filename = rand_thumbnail_pic)
embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://" + rand_thumbnail_pic)

async with context.channel.typing(): 
    await context.message.add_reaction('\u2665') 
    await(await context.channel.send (file = mem_file_info, embed = embed)).delete (delay = 300)  
await context.message.delete (delay = 4)
```

Note: * replaces any personal information

Comment: Using `/` for the file separator works just as well and is less cluttery.

Comment: Try using the os module.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to do that so I am able to attach both messages to the embed?